# How to Import some data into a different table name in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, import, datapump

Please i have a table export that was performed using datapump,
and now I want to restore the dump on an archive oracle database, but on a different table name,
this table contains lots of partitions, my script is below,

Note: STG_CDR.MSC_CDR_2 is the new table that was created on the new database
STG_CDR.MSC_CDR   is the old table that was exported into the dump

`    directory=IMP_TBS_BK2
dumpfile=TBS_TS_STG_CDR_M_3M201907_01.dmp,TBS_TS_STG_CDR_M_3M201907_02.dmp,TBS_TS_STG_CDR_M_3M201907_03.dmp

```
logfile=IMP_MSC_CDR_2_201907_1.log

REMAP_SCHEMA=STG_CDR:STG_CDR
REMAP_TABLE=STG_CDR.MSC_CDR:MSC_CDR_2

tables=STG_CDR.MSC_CDR_2:P_20190701,
STG_CDR.MSC_CDR_2:P_20190702,
STG_CDR.MSC_CDR_2:P_20190703,
STG_CDR.MSC_CDR_2:P_20190704,
STG_CDR.MSC_CDR_2:P_20190705,
STG_CDR.MSC_CDR_2:P_20190706

parallel=4 
table_exists_action=append 
job_name=IMP_MSC_CDR_2_201907_1`
```

But i'm getting error that table does not exit

Comment: Without seeing the full error message, I think it is probably MSC_CDR_2 in the 'tables=' spec. It needs to be MSC_CDR

Comment: hello @gsalem i tried it also, still the same error.

Comment: can you add the full error message to your question?

Comment: hi @gsalem this is the error i'm currently getting below:

ORA-39166: Object STG_CDR.MSC_CDR was not found or could not be exported or imported.
ORA-39164: Partition STG_CDR.MSC_CDR:P_20190705 was not found.
ORA-39164: Partition STG_CDR.MSC_CDR:P_20190704 was not found.
ORA-39164: Partition STG_CDR.MSC_CDR:P_20190703 was not found.
ORA-39164: Partition STG_CDR.MSC_CDR:P_20190702 was not found.
ORA-39164: Partition STG_CDR.MSC_CDR:P_20190701 was not found.
<br>
But these partitions exist on the new table created

Comment: Do these partitions exist in the MSC_CDR table? Are you sure that table exists in the dmp files?

Comment: I'll checking the dump logs, it seems they are missing from this current set of dumps. I will check other dumps, thanks @gsalem